# Devolver un array con solo los enteros de una función llamada 'soloNumeros' que contiene enteros y strings

Tags: javascript

La función 'checkInventario' recibe como argumento un *array* de objetos llamado 'inventario' y el nombre de un *ítem* llamado 'item'. Cada objeto tiene una propiedad 'nombre' y 'cantidad'.

La función debe devolver la cantidad de *ítems* que hay. Si el *ítem* no existe la función tiene que devolver 0 (cero). Ej:

```js
var inventario = [
  { nombre: "tenedor", cantidad: 6 },
  { nombre: "cuchara", cantidad: 4 },
];

checkInventario(inventario, "tenedor"); // devuelve => 6
```

Lo que yo hice fue:

```js
    var x = [];
    function checkInventario(inventario, item) {
      for (i = 0; i < inventario.length; i++) {
        if (inventario[i].nombre === item) {
          x.push(inventario[i].cantidad);
        }
        return x;
      }
    } return 0
}
```

El problema es que no me dice la cantidad de *ítems* que tengo en `inventario`.

Comment: declara una variable tipo arreglo ejemplo `x` ,en vez de return que esta dentro del for coloca `x.push(inventario[i].cantidad)` y al final del for coloca el `return  x`

Comment: por cierto bienvenido a stackoverflow en español te invito a hacer el [tour]

Comment: disculpa pero ¿como seria lo del arreglo x ?

Comment: algo como `var x =[]`

Comment: dale lo voy a probar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: no sale, no se si me equivoque en algo yo

Answer (score 1):

sugerencia, es una función para una tarea especifica, esta solo debe regresar el valor que deses, no almacenarlo en una variable externa a la función pues pierde su reusabilidad
Posible solución

```
function checkInventario(inventario, item) {
for (i = 0; i < inventario.length; i++) {
  if (inventario[i].nombre === item) {
    return inventario[i].cantidad
    }
  }
 return 0 
}
```

output

```
checkInventario(inventario, 'cuchara')    //retorna 4
checkInventario(inventario, 'x')          //retorna 0
```

Una ves hecho esto puedes llamar la función y asignar el valor que regrese a una variable

```
let variable = checkInventario(inventario, 'x')
console.log(variable) // log 0
```

Answer (score 1):

### Caso N.º 1

Si partimos de la idea de lo que plantea el título de la publicación, cito:

> Devolver un arreglo con solo los enteros de una función llamada 'soloNumeros', que contiene enteros y strings

Podríamos definirla así (solo que ahora es denominada `checkInventario`):

```js
const inventario = [
  { nombre: 'tenedor', cantidad: 6 },
  { nombre: 'cuchara', cantidad: 4,}
];

// Nuestra función:
const checkInventario = (inventario, item) => {
  const cantidades = inventario
    .filter(value => value.nombre === item && value.cantidad)
    .map(value => value.cantidad);

  return cantidades.length > 0 ? cantidades : 0;
}

// Mostrar resultados:
console.log(checkInventario(inventario, "tenedor") );
```

#### Explicación

Lo que se hizo en este caso fue definir un *array* denominado `cantidades` con la intención de recoger números de la propiedad `cantidad` de cada objeto almacenado en el *array* `inventario`, es decir:

```js
const cantidades = inventario
  .filter((value) => value.nombre === item && value.cantidad)
  .map((value) => value.cantidad);
```

Donde el método `.filter` filtra los resultados utilizando la siguiente coincidencia:

```js
value.nombre === item && value.cantidad
```

Es decir, si la propiedad `.nombre` coincide con `item` y además, está definida la propiedad `.cantidad` en cada objeto evaluado durante la iteración estos serán los elementos de `cantidades`.

Sin embargo, como lo que se quiere obtener es un *array* de números se utiliza, además de `.filter` el mètodo `.map`, es decir:

```js
...
.map((value) => value.cantidad);
```

Para devolver el valor almacenado en `value.cantidad` y no el objeto entero.

Para finalizar, necesitamos que nuestra función devuelva el *array* de números o simplemente un `0` en función de si se formó dicho *array*.

Es decir, mediante la utilización de *operador ternario*:

```js
return cantidades.length > 0 ? cantidades : 0;
```

Pero podemos hacer que nuestra función devuelva siempre números enteros o array de números enteros con independencia de que la propiedad `cantidad` de cada objeto exista o no o tenga un tipo de datos que sea diferente de un número.

Es decir:

```js
const inventario = [
  { nombre: 'tenedor', cantidad: 6 },
  { nombre: 'cuchara', cantidad: 4,}
];

// Nuestra función:
const checkInventario = (inventario, item) => {
  const cantidades = inventario
    .filter(value => value.nombre === item && !isNaN(value.cantidad))
    .map(value => parseInt(value.cantidad));

  return cantidades.length > 0 ? cantidades : 0;
}

// Mostrar resultados:
console.log(checkInventario(inventario, "tenedor") );
```

Se cambió esta línea:

```js
.filter(value => value.nombre === item && value.cantidad)
```

Por esta otra en el método `.filter`:

```js
.filter(value => value.nombre === item && !isNaN(value.cantidad))
```

Y en el método `.map` se cambió esta:

```js
.map(value => value.cantidad);
```

Por esta otra:

```js
.map(value => parseInt(value.cantidad));
```

---

### Caso N.º 2

Ahora bien, si lo que quiere lograr es un resultado similar a este:

```js
checkInventario(inventario, "tenedor"); // devuelve => 6
```

Puedes definir la función`checkInventario( inventario, item )` de la siguiente manera:

```js
const inventario = [
  { nombre: 'tenedor', cantidad: 6 },
  { nombre: 'cuchara', cantidad: 4,}
];

// Nuestra función:
const checkInventario = (inventario, item) => {
  const _item = inventario.find(value => value.nombre == item);
  const { cantidad = 0 } = _item ? _item : {};

  return !isNaN(cantidad) ? parseInt(cantidad) : 0;
}

// Mostrar resultados:
console.log(checkInventario(inventario, "tenedor") );
```

#### Explicación:

La línea:

```js
const _item = inventario.find((value) => value.nombre == item);
```

O su equivalente, que también puede ser expresado así:

```js
const _item = inventario.find((value) => {
  return value.nombre == item;
});
```

Lo que hace es almacenar un *objeto* (si lo encuentra) en una constante `_item` que desestructuraremos en la siguiente línea:

```js
const { cantidad = 0 } = _item ? _item : {};
```

Es decir, `cantidad` es nuestra propiedad obtenida del objeto `_item`. En caso de no estar definido tendrá como valor por defecto el `0`.

Note que la siguiente línea:

```js
_item ? _item : {};
```

Es un operador ternario, es decir, que si `_item` está definido se tomará, de lo contrario, el valor tomado será un objeto vacío. En cualquiera de los casos, se desestructurará en `cantidad` si efectivamente [`_item`] está definida, de lo contrario, [`cantidad`] tomará el valor `0` por defecto.

Observe que la línea:

```js
return !isNaN(cantidad) ? parseInt(cantidad) : 0;
```

También tiene un operador ternario. En ella se evalúa si `cantidad` es un número, de serlo, obtener de él un entero [con `parseInt(cantidad)`], de lo contrario, su valor por defecto será `0`.

#### Agregando validación al primer parámetro de la función

Podemos hacer que nuestra función devuelva `0` por defecto si no se le pasan parámetros. Esto hará que nuestra función sea más funcional:

```js
const inventario = [
  { nombre: 'tenedor', cantidad: 6 },
  { nombre: 'cuchara', cantidad: 4,}
];


// Nuestra función:
const checkInventario = (inventario, item) => {
  if ( !Array.isArray(inventario) )
    return 0;

  const _item = inventario.find(value => value.nombre == item);
  const { cantidad = 0 } = _item ? _item : {};

  return !isNaN(cantidad) ? parseInt(cantidad) : 0;
}

// Mostrar resultados:
console.log(checkInventario( inventario ) );
console.log(checkInventario( inventario, "cuchara" ) );
console.log(checkInventario( inventario, "Cualquier cosa" ) );
```

En esta oportunidad solo se ha agregado las líneas:

```js
if (!Array.isArray(inventario))
    return 0;
```

Al comienzo de la función `checkInventario` para validar que nuestro parámetro `inventario` sea un *array*. Con esta validación extra se asegura que la función devuelva `0` como valor por defecto, siempre que se haya incluido la siguiente línea en ella:

```js
const { cantidad = 0 } = _item ? _item : {};
```

Que ya ha sido explicada anteriormente en esta publicación.

#### Referencias

- [**`Array.prototype.find()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [**`Array.prototype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [**`Array.prototype.map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [**`Operador condicional (ternario)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 1):

Se puede solucionar de la siguiente manera:

> 1. Utilizamos el método find para mapear al arreglo, lo cual se va a comparar con el método startsWith
> 2. Como entendemos que el método find cuando no encuentra la comparación nos arroja undefined, podemos partir de hay para hacer la
>    evaluación, utilizando **!!data** nos indica es que hace **match** podemos
>    mostrar en consola el valor, mediante **data.cantidad** de lo contrario será 0

```js
 var inventarios = [
    { nombre: "tenedor", cantidad: 6 },
    { nombre: "cuchara", cantidad: 4 }
  ];

  console.log(checkInventario(inventarios, "tenedor"));
  console.log(checkInventario(inventarios, "cuchillo"));

  function checkInventario(inventario, item) {
    const data = inventario.find((i) => i.nombre.startsWith(item));
    return !!data ? data.cantidad : 0;
  }
```